# How can I determine how much distance I have scrolled?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a image inside a ScrollViewer. I display the Image by its original size. The Image's is larger than the ScrollViewer's size.

Now I want to know how much height/width I have scrolled.

There are ScrollableHeight and ScrollableWidth property on ScrollViewer to tell me the maximum distance that can be scrolled. What I want is the actual scrolled distance.

If I scroll up 1 step and scroll down 1 step, the distance should be 0. The ScrollViewer display the image correctly when scrolling, so there should be a way of getting that distance.

Anybody knows how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, VerticalOffset and HorizontalOffset gives that I want.